# Number in textfield should be autoformatted only after user clicks outside the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a problem. Basically, what happens in my case is that the numbers in my textbox are autoformatted as I type. I don't want this to happen. What I want is that the numbers should be autoformatted only when the user clicks outside the textbox.

In my input tag I have :

```
   onkeyup="format(event, this);"
```

My javascript function is :

```
function format(e, obj) {
    if (e.keyCode == 36) {
        press1(obj);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }

    if ((e.keyCode <= 34) || (e.keyCode >= 46 && e.keyCode < 58) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) { // //alert(e.keyCode);

        obj.value = CommaFormatted(obj.value);
    } else {
        if (e && e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

where the press1 function is:

```
function press1(textControlID) {

    var text = textControlID;
    if (text.getAttribute("maxlength") == text.value.length) {
        var FieldRange = text.createTextRange();
        FieldRange.moveStart('character', text.value.length);
        FieldRange.collapse();
        FieldRange.select();
        return true;
    }
    if (text != null && text.value.length > 0) {
        if (text.createTextRange) {
            var FieldRange = text.createTextRange();
            FieldRange.moveStart('character', text.value.length);
            FieldRange.collapse();
            FieldRange.select();
        } else if (text.setSelectionRange) {
            var textLength = text.value.length;
            text.setSelectionRange(textLength, textLength);
        }
    }
}
```

I really hope this could be solved. Please!

Answer (score 0):

You could change `onkeyup` to `onblur`, which is the event that gets fired when the control loses focus - clicking out of it.

The `onkeyup` event fires with every keypress.

Comment: Sorry but that did not work! Also some of the validation logic was affected. Thanks!

Comment: hah, you'll need to change the logic as `e.keycode` won't exist to compare against as it's not a keypress event anymore. You should be able to figure that out by stepping through the code?

Comment: Correct, but I cannot change the logic at any cost.

Comment: In that case you have to leave it as it is? There's a fundamental difference between validation logic which fires with every keypress and that which takes place once when the control has lost focus...

Comment: By the way Starscream...is there a replacement for e.keycode?

Comment: `e.keycode` tells you which key has been pressed. This makes sense when you are capturing a key press event, but of course it doesn't make sense when you are capturing an element focus event.